# Material-ui: How to stop propagation of click event in nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an `IconMenu` component inside a `Paper` component.
I would like to prevent the propagation of the click event on the inner component (the `IconMenu`).
That's what I came up with, without significant results (I also tried substituting onClick with `onTouchTap`, `onMouseUp` with same effects): the `_iconMenuClick` method is never called.

```
render() {
     return (
         <Paper onClick={this._onClick}>
             <IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement} onClick={this._iconMenuClick}>
                 {menuItems}
             </IconMenu>
         </Paper>
     );
}

_iconMenuClick(event) {
    MenuItem.onClick(event);
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 18):

In addition to using `event.stopPropagation();`
It is useful to note that it should be written within a `onClick` event handler.

I made the mistake of writing it inside an `onChange` event handler, and that wasn't working.

I found that solution [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11928)

EDIT:

```
<ListItem button onClick={this.handleListItemClick}>
-       <Checkbox onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
+       <Checkbox onClick={this.handleCheckboxChange} />
      </ListItem>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: omg this worked :O 
Wonder why no one mentioned it. I was scratching my head for past hour to understand why such basic piece of code is not working.
Thanks for this vital piece of information.

Answer (score 14):

For stopping top node bubble events :-)

`event.stopPropagation();
event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I suggest is the following:

```
render() {
     return (
         <Paper onClick={this._onClick}>
             <IconMenu iconButtonElement={iconButtonElement}>
                 {menuItems}
             </IconMenu>
             ...
         </Paper>
     );
}

_onClick(event){
    if(event.target.innerText==""){ //Or any condition that distinguish the IconMenu from the Paper element
        event.stopPropagation();
        return 0;
    }
    //continue with normal behaviour
    ...
}
```